# Django - pass js variable to django view

Tags: python, django, google-maps-api-3

My question is related to the Google Maps JavaScript API. More specific the autocomplete function.

I've added the autocomplete function as a search bar to my test site and this works fine, but now I want to pass the chosen paramater to a Django view. And here I'm stuck.

This is what I have in my template:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function initialize() {
      var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
      var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
   }
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
   google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
   var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
   });
</script>

<form method="post" action="">{% csrf_token %}
    <input id="searchTextField" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location" autocomplete="on">
    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="postfix button"/>
</form>
```

And this in my view:

```
def homepage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        location = request.POST
else:
    location = ''
return render_to_response('homepage.html', {'location':location}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

What I want to do is to pass the variable 'place' to the variable 'location' in my Django view (the var place should contain the lat and lon, and this I want to use then further in Geodjango). The `request.POST` gives the following: `<QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'4xp3nNwzeITb1zHhkBkSGlZSPtGwmuMB']}>` But this I can't use.

Is it possible to pass the content of var place to the django view?

Thanks for the feedback!

EDIT:
my workaround for the moment using geopy:

Template:

```
<input id="searchTextField" name="searchTextField" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location" autocomplete="on">
```

View:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    location = request.POST.get('searchTextField')
    gn = geocoders.Google()  
    place, (lat, lng) = gn.geocode(location)
```

Still looking for a way to access the `var place` in the `script`. Is this possible?

Comment: Create a hidden field, and set its value to `place` using javascript; and trigger populating of this using jquery on form's submit button.

Comment: What @BurhanKhalid said. You need to use javascript to get the place value into the form, then when you submit the form it will be sent to your Django view and you can access it the same way... `request.POST.get('place')`.

Comment: Thx for the reply. Add the end of the script I added the following: `document.getElementById('place').value = autocomplete.getPlace();` and in the `form` I inserted an extra input field: `<input id="place" name="place" type="text" />`. But the value of field `place` remains empty. Is this because the `var place` is not calculated before the form is submitted?

Answer (score 3):

First add a `name` attribute to your search input. Let's say you called it `searchTextField` like the `id`. Then you can do `request.POST.get('searchTextField')`.

Comment: Thx for the reply. Indeed yesterday evening I build a workaround based on the name of the field. see my update. But still looking for a way to access the `var place` in the `script`.

Comment: @Katy lavallee. I have a question in a similar context. I have a function in view.py say 'def home(request)'. Now I want to access the variable/value at "static/DjangoApp/DjangoApp.js". I know to access the values at html page by rendering the page like this: return render(request, 'search_bar/home.html', {'table': table_name}). but how we can access value at .js page. any hint would be really appreciable.

Comment: @girijesh96 Generally you would submit the form via Javascript. I don't know enough about Google's autocomplete input to know if you can post it as a normal HTML form.

Comment: @girijesh96 also, did you see the first comment on the original question? you can create a hidden field and use javascript to set the value of that field to the value in your autocomplete box.