# Django - Google Maps API - pass JS variables to view.py through forms

Tags: javascript, django, google-maps

There are a lot of gaps in my knowledge, so I may be trying to solve this the wrong way. The goal is to use this [Google Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform) to autocomplete and parse address input, and save the results in a model.

I couldn't find a way to pass variables from JS directly to `view.py`, so now the plan is to have the JS fill a hidden field [as suggested by a previous unsolved question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890840/django-pass-js-variable-to-django-view).

Could the fields generated by a `ModelForm` be used for this? If not, how should the form be created so that the JS fills in the fields, the fields are hidden and unchangeable by users, and it makes use of `csrf_token`?

This is all I have so far. There are a bunch of `input` fields that get filled automatically by the JS. The `form|crispy` generated by `ModelForm` doesn't get filled, even though the `id` is the same (field names in `models.py` are the same as Google's naming scheme). I don't understand how the last paragraph of the JS works, that's likely where I'm stuck.

**Update:**
The following code is not giving a POST, why?

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/place/new',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
        address: 'test'
    },
    success: function (response, textStatus, error) {
        console.log('SUCCESS')
    },
    error: function (request, textStatus, error) {
        console.log('error')
        console.log(place)
    }
});
<!-- end snippet -->

<!-- language: lang-python -->

def placenew(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        test = request.POST.get('address')
        response_data = {}
        print (test)
        print ("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^")
        return render(request, 'app/placenew.html', {'key':key})
    else:
        print ("not POST")
        return render(request, 'app/placenew.html', {'key':key})

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to pass variables from the JS to django then you could look at posting an ajax request to your view and providing whatever data you want in the `data` attribute.

For example, I'm in the middle of doing exactly this using Knockout JS so I have this ajax request;

```
$.ajax({
    url: URLS.design,
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
        data: ko.mapping.toJSON(structure_data)
    },
    success: function (response, textStatus, error) {
        console.log('SUCCESS')
    },
    error: function (request, textStatus, error) {
        console.log('error')
    }
});
```

You could get the field values, variables or whatever else you wanted and pass them in the `data` attribute of `$.ajax`.

Alternatively you could setup fields in your ModelForm with the `HiddenInput()` widget so your javascript can populate them, without your user worrying about them. Then if they were populated correctly, you could just post the form & your data would be sent to the view.

To read up on Ajax, this looks like a great article; https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-and-ajax-form-submissions/

Essentially the `url` attribute would just be somewhere you've got your view setup like `/myapp/myview/` and then in your view it's very similar to how you'd handle any normal POST request. For example, I'm currently doing this with the above bit of Javascript when it hits my view;

```
def get_forms(self, forms):
    data = None

    if self.request.method in ('POST', 'PUT'):

        if self.request.is_ajax():
            _json = self.request.POST.get('data')
            data = json.loads(_json)
        else:
            data = self.request.POST
```

**Update**

Well first of all when you're defining your URL, make sure you include a trailing slash or when it hits Django it'll get redirected. So you'll want `url: '/place/new/'`.

Also, your response from the server should return JSON if it's received an AJAX request. So you might do something like;

```
def placenew(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        test = request.POST.get('address')
        response_data = {}

        if request.is_ajax():
            return HttpResponse(
                json.dumps(response_data),
                content_type="application/json"
            )
        return render(
            request, 'app/placenew.html', {'key':key}
        )
    else:
        print ("not POST")
        return render(request, 'app/placenew.html', {'key':key})
```

Also, I'm assuming you've followed that tutorial and have your ajax call defined within a function which you trigger somehow when your form is submitted?

Comment: I have zero experience with Ajax, where do I put the code and is there anything to install? As for the alternative, I'm trying that now and the `id` seems to match the one in the example, but it doesn't fill in. Edit: nevermind, apparently Django puts `id_` in front of the id and that's probably the reason it doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah that's standard for django rendering forms. I've updated my answer with some more detail & a good link for an article on django & ajax.

Comment: I changed it to `url: '/place/new/'` and it didn't fix it. I did follow the tutorial as best I could, and I know it is being called because `console.log('error')` works and it also logs the correct information in `place`. I don't quite understand what's going on inside `if request.is_ajax():`, but I copied it in and it still prints `not POST`.

Comment: The `not POST` is printing as the first thing when I load the page, and no messages print after running the autocomplete. F12 shows the `console.log('error')`, so that means the AJAX isn't sending anything to the view?

Comment: @vandidant That's correct. The first time you load that page you're performing a `GET` request, not a `POST`. When you submit a form to that view with a `method=post` it'll send a `POST` request.

Comment: sorry for the edit just as you commented. In that case I'm pretty sure that the problem exists in the JS, any idea what it is? I tried both the `csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',` that I took from another STO answer, and the huge chunk of csrf code linked in the tutorial, both same results. Also, the only script that this needs is `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script> `, correct?

Comment: Something happened now, it gives an error message `Line: 38
Error: Unable to get property 'lat' of undefined or null reference`

Comment: @vandidant Well you're obviously trying to get something called `lat` from something expected to be passed to whatever that is. I'm assuming because you want to use the Google Maps API that you should be posting an object/data to a view where you then get the lat/long of that object? Take a look at line 38 of whatever file that is coming from.

Comment: The file it's coming from is the API script, it's a minified mess. You gave me an idea, I don't really have to parse it in the view, I could parse it in JS and just pass over a bunch of things under `data`, or alternatively put everything in a smaller JSON and pass that over without the error. Just to confirm, if `place` is JSON, it is the same as a Python dictionary, and `address: place` is the correct syntax?

Comment: @vandidant Yeah it basically looks like a dict.

Comment: I can't get this to work, it's taking up too much time so I'm going to give up for now. Thanks for your help though.